# How to get original (All store views) current category name in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

How can I get "original" category name in Magento where I already translated category name for current store view. I would like to get category name as entered in All Store views because I would like to send original (English) name to GA for tracking - I need this when I'm on category page.

I can get localized category name in this way:

```
<?php 
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$name = $currentCategory->getName();
?>
```

But couldn't find a way to get untranslated name without additional calls to database.

Comment: This will need additional calls to the database. So probably you already found the solution.

Comment: I'm still searching for solution, even with additional DB calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned above, this will need additional database requests. The following should work:

```
$defaultStoreCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$defaultStoreCategory->setStoreId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID);
$defaultStoreCategory->load($currentCategory->getId());

$name = $defaultStoreCategory->getName();
```

Comment: This fails in Magento 1.7: "Fatal error: Call to a member function setStoreId() on a non-object"

Comment: My bad, it should be `getResource()`, not `getResourceModel()`. I'll update the answer...

Comment: Your code still gives me localized category name, but if I omit call to "getResource()" and call directly "setStoreId()" on model (as @magento-code below suggested) then it works

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
     ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
     ->load(YOUR_CATEGORY_ID);
```

Hope this helps.